# How to filter with a data which is greater than current date in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

filter data which is greater than current date

```
select * from event_participant where username='$username' AND event_date>=GETDATE()
```

I have been try this query but seems doesn't works

Comment: Is the `event_date` column of a *date* datatype?

Comment: yes, its datatype is date

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `CURDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM event_participant
WHERE username = '$username'
    AND event_date >= CURDATE()
```

**Mysql**: `NOW()`, `CURDATE()`

**SQL Server**: `GETDATE()`